# How to extract an enum from a class in JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a class which is passing to a native method as shown here

```
public enum Color{  
         eRED,
         eGREEN,
         eBLUE};

public class ConfigColor{   
         public ColorE color;   
         public int value;};

public native int HelloWord(ConfigColor ConfigColorcls);

ConfigColor clsConfigColor = new ConfigColor();
clsConfigColor .color = eGREEN;
clsConfigColor . value = 255;

HelloWord(clsConfigColor);
```

I can extract the `int value` using GetIntField and GetObjectClass. But how to extract the `ColorE color`? Please help

Answer (score 1):

To get the value , you may use following

```
public static Color getFromInt(int id) {
    for (Color candidate : Color.values()) {
        if (candidate.getAsInt() == id) {
            return candidate;
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("no Color " + id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think you get get the enum per-se, as the JNI supported types don't say nothing about enum:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp9502

That's pretty normal I guess, the Java enum is pretty specific to Java.

What you can do is get your enum instance as an object, invoke the name() method and you get the String containing your enum type (such as "eRED"), then you can use that. If the class you call via JNI is also a Java class that has access to the enum, you can do :

```
ColorEnum colorEnumInstance = ColorEnum.valueOf("eGREEN");
```

Comment: So it means that it’s impossible to parse enum from a class in JNI?

Comment: Yes pretty much that's what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetObjectClass` to get the class object, and then invoke `getName()` on that. You'll get a `jstring`, for example "eRED". That's your enum, but it may not be the most useful form.

Alternatively, consider associating an integer with your enum like this:

```
public enum Color {
    eRED(0),
    eGREEN(1),
    eBLUE(2);

    private Color(int numer) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public final int number; // Maybe a byte would suffice...
}
```

This is analogous to C enums, which are really just (named) integers. Then you could access the enum's `number` field directly in C, instead of parsing strings.

Comment: Or you could just use the Enum class's ordinal.